# Laravel Valet stopped working after update

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I get the following errors if I try to access any .dev sites.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/var/root/.valet/config.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Users/User/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php on line 23

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/User/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php on line 47
404 - Not Found
```

It worked fine, ran the update as per the instructions and using the following commands:

1. composer global update
2. valet install

updated from 1.1.X to 1.1.18

Comment: Did you run either of those commands as `sudo` per chance?